# JQuery - disable dynamically generated form elements / buttons

Tags: jquery, forms, button, dynamic, disabled-input

I have a DIV with a bunch of dynamically generated form buttons (fetched via AJAX).

I'm trying to find out how to `disable` dynamically generated form buttons(e.g lets say a some form buttons were fetched using ajax and displayed in a div. I have my dynamic buttons placed inside a DIV with class `buttonContainer`.

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
 $(".buttonContainer").find('*').prop("disabled", true);
```

Somewhat related, but I do know how use JQuery to catch events from dynamically generated form elements by placing those dynamic form elements in a parent DIV and telling that DIV to capture their events when propagated upwards in the DOM, see following where my dynamic buttons are using class `btn-timeselection`.

```
$(".buttonContainer").on( "click",  ".btn-timeselection", function(eventObject)  {
  event.preventDefault();
  var item = $(this);
  $(".btn-timeselection").removeClass("btn-orange");
  $(".btn-timeselection").addClass("btn-grey");
  item.addClass("btn-orange");
});
```

So yes, back to the original question, how to disable these dynamic buttons?

Comment: in function(eventObject) it is eventObject and you have used event.preventDefault();, how come?

Comment: are you using this $(".buttonContainer").find('*').prop("disabled", true); after ajax success?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Thanks I placed the code in the Ajax Success, and it works. I would have preferred to have left it outside the success handler though, but i guess if it works it works.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick for you

```
$('.buttonContainer').find('button').attr('disabled','disabled');
```